# Return custom errors WebApi ASP.NET 5 HttpResponseException wrong status code

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net5

WebAPI / REST allows you to send custom error messages together with a standard Status Code, i.e. 402 - Not found + your own message in the header / body.

This works great on ASP.NET 4.X, but with ASP.NET 5 RC 1 there's something amiss.

While my code to throw custom errors looks something like this:

```cs
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous) 
{ 
    Content = feedback, ReasonPhrase = reason }
);
```

The code returned (to Angular) isn't the code specified (300 in the example).
On localhost / IIS Express i get `500 Internal Server Error` and in production on Azure I get `404 Not Found`.

Looking at the ASP.NET docs I see something that might be relevant:

> If the server catches an exception before the headers have been sent
>   it will send a 500 Internal Server Error response with no body.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/error-handling.html#server-exception-handling

So has anyone successfully returned status codes with custom (body) messages to client from ASP.NET 5 RC 1 WebAPI?

**UPDATE:**

This methodology seems to work better - but that doesn't answer why `HttpResponseException` doesn't work.

```cs
this.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return this.HttpBadRequest(new { ex.Message });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your updated question, they removed that use of HttpResponseException because it encouraged the bad practice of using exceptions for flow control. See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4311.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Documentation is badly lacking